# How can I detect the boundaries of an irregular shape?

Tags: ios, view, touch

I am developing a painting app,in which i'll be having different images of irregular objects like animals,flowers etc..and i want that when user starts painting using a color,color should not go out side the boundaries of that object..help me in detecting the boundaries of a irregular bodily object...

Comment: https://github.com/chinatndave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a 2d flood fill algorithm. It's fairly straightforward once you understand the recursive nature of the algorithm.  Posting code here for the whole thing would take up far too much space. There's a great article on this here:

[QuickFill Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6017/QuickFill-An-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm)

I just reread your question. The above would help but you may just want to use a masking layer and an editable layer. The making layer would be drawn over the "editable" layer, having complete transparency where the user can paint.

Comment: thanks for your response,but i dont want it to be filled all at once,rather as user moves his/her finger on the image..it gets coloured along with the movement of finger...thanks in advance

Comment: In this case, yes, use two layers, one the user can draw in, and the other drawn over this layer. This will simulate keeping the user "in the lines".

Comment: If the pixels can hold more information, you could have a "boundary" flag on each one. You paint a pixel during a drag event if it's not a boundary and if at least one of its neighbours has been painted as well (the first pixel of each stroke gets painted in the touch event).

Comment: Can some one help in getting bounds of drawing area...

Answer (score 0):

You need either a low pass filter (detect, but not change) or a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) solution.

Comment: thanks for your response,but i dont want it to be filled all at once,rather as user moves his/her finger on the image..it gets coloured along with the movement of finger...thanks in advance

Comment: And that's where a low filter comes in. In the event that handles user drag, a pixel is painted if these conditions are met: it's not been painted before, at least one neighbour was painted, and the painted neighbours don't change color information abruptly. Alternatively, if all boundaries are of the same color, you just stop coloring there.